# Error when grabbing the data from API using Alamofire

Tags: swift, api, alamofire

I'm experiencing an issue where I'm getting an error when trying to access an API for my game server. My code is:

```
@IBAction func search(_ sender: Any) {
            let url = "https://api.nethergames.org/?action=voteCheck&player=\(usernameVoterInput.text)"

            Alamofire.request(url, method: .get)
                .responseJSON { response in
                    if response.result.isSuccess {

                        print("Sucess! Got the user data!.")
                        let newVoteJSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
                        self.voteJSON = newVoteJSON

                        self.updateLabelsVoted(json: self.voteJSON)

                    } else {
                        print("Error")
                    }
            }

    }
```

When I run the app and press the button it prints "Error" in the console. I'm using the pods Alamofire & SwiftyJSON in my file. I'm also using another piece of code to get the API for something else in that same file and that works fine.

If you need to see more code I can supply more, thanks.

Comment: would you mind always print error description. print("Error \(response.error)")

Comment: @tereks Here's the Error: Optional(Alamofire.AFError.invalidURL("https://api.nethergames.org/?action=voteCheck&player=Optional(\"Callum9966\")"))

Comment: Ок, do you see whats the problem?

Comment: No sorry, I don't really understand it. Only about 3 months into Swift.

Comment: I don't see explanation in selected answer so here we go: your *url* string is wrong. *usernameVoterInput.text* returns optional value, so when you construct string var with optional value you get text like "Optional("Username")" instead of "Username". Thats why url request is failed. You need to unwrap optional value before creating string with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to call the API and it works. Here is my chunk of code:

```
func callAPI() {
    let url = "https://api.nethergames.org/?action=voteCheck&player=CakeGammerJ1"

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get)
    .responseJSON { response in
        if response.result.isSuccess {

        print("Sucess! Got the user data!.")
        print(response.description)

    } else {
        print("Error")
    }
}
```

It prints:

```
SUCCESS: {
    player = cakegammerj1;
    status = 1;
}
```

I've used Alamofire version 4.5.1.
I hope, it'll help you to resolve the issue.